# How to reply an employer that I am still in the market looking for job?

Tags: new-job, recruitment, human-resources, email, careers

I recently applied for a position.The employer mailed me saying that its for more experienced person and
"If you are still in the market for new employment with a young, growing commercial IT business please let me know"

How should I reply to this message and Yes I am still in the market looking for job

Cheers

Answer (score 12):

> How should I reply to this message and Yes I am still in the market
>   looking for job

It appears that they are trying to signal to you that they have other positions requiring less experience.

**If you are interested in a less senior position with this company, then get back in contact with them and reply that Yes, you are still on the market, and would love to discuss other open positions with them.**

This could be a great opportunity if you didn't have your heart set on the specific original position. It's certainly worth a reply.

Answer (score 2):

Then, your reply should be straightforward and precise. I would reply with the below message:

> Dear XXX,
>
> Thank you for replying.
>
> I am still in the market, looking for challenging opportunities in the domain of XYZ.
>
> So, if you have any such opportunity which would fit my profile, then do let me know.
>
> regards,
>
> YYY